FFmpeg with quick sync video works wrong
I have been using for quite some time, ffmpeg in ubuntu for video file conversion. I use nvidia hardware accelerator successfully and without any particular problems. On some machines I tried using the built-in accelerators in Intel cpu's, first vaapi and then qsv and here the problems started.
I have a machine with a 10th generation i7 cpu, I had compiled and installed ffmpeg enabling qsv support and everything worked. After the last system update, despite the fact that I ran the same instructions used before, we formatted the system and followed intel's instructions, the hardware support does not work, the transcoding speed is ridiculous and it is impossible to use the filters. I have installed all the dependencies (libva, gmmlib, media-intel, msdk etc.) but the result is still very bad.  Does anyone have experience with this or a guide for debugging?
if I use vaapi instead of qsv, the filters work but the speed is significantly lower than what I could get using qsv

thanks for reply
the goal is to create a hybrid conversion, using qsv as decoder and nvenc as encoder. Before the update everything worked with very good execution speed.
ffmpeg is compiled as per the instruction
--extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-cuvid --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable- libnpp --enable-libfreetype --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openssl --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmfx --enable-vaapi --enable-libharfbuzz
(I tried to compile it with -enable-vpl to use oneVPL, but then ffmpeg can't find qsv-compatible hardware)
the command I used successfully is this:
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel error -stats -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -i input. ts -filter_complex scale_qsv=-1:720,hwdownload,format=nv12,pad=“in_w:in_h+40:0:-0”, “drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans. ttf: text='%{pts:localtime:$2}':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-th -10: fontcolor=white: fontsize=30: rate=25”,hwupload_cuda,yadif_cuda -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 500k -maxrate 600k -bufsize 250k -c:a aac -b:a 64k -ac 2 -r 25 output.mp4
after updating qsv works with the performance I expect only without filters:
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel error -stats -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -i input.ts -c:v h264_qsv -b:v 500k -maxrate 600k -bufsize 250k -c:a aac -[enter image description here][1]b:a 64k -ac 2 -r 25 output.mp4
as soon as I add the filters, the conversion speed does not exceed 1x and the produced movie has correct audio, but blocked video.
Made exceptions for some error in the input file, but they are more warnings than errors, ffmpeg does not produce any error during execution but a lot of frame duplicated
[h264 @ 0x5636d2f99000] number of reference frames (0+5) exceeds max (4; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[h264 @ 0x5636d2f99000] mmco: unref short failure
Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 0x5636d3079440] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 0x5636d3079440] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 339692301).
Input #0, mpegts, from '/media/Registrazioni/Tv/Boing/2024-09-01/Boing_20240901_1600.ts':
Duration: 01:00:59.86, start: 115.030900, bitrate: 2190 kb/s
Program 1
Metadata:
service_name    : Boing HD
service_provider: Mediaset
Stream #0:0[0x3f1]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn
Stream #0:10x455: Audio: eac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s
File '/media/Registrazioni/Tv/Boing/2024-09-01/Boing_20240901_16.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (h264_qsv) -> scale_qsv:default
hwupload_cuda:default -> Stream #0:0 (h264_nvenc)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (eac3 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to '/media/Registrazioni/Tv/Boing/2024-09-01/Boing_20240901_16.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf61.5.101
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), cuda(tv, bt709, top coded first (swapped)), 1280x760 [SAR 1:1 DAR 32:19], q=2-31, 500 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavc61.11.100 h264_nvenc
Side data:
cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 600000/0/500000 buffer size: 250000 vbv_delay: N/A
Stream #0:1(ita): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavc61.11.100 aac
[out#0/mp4 @ 0x5636d326dc40] video:136KiB audio:79KiB subtitle:0KiB other streams:0KiB global headers:0KiB muxing overhead: 4.117989%
frame=  250 fps=188 q=22.0 Lsize=     224KiB time=00:00:09.88 bitrate= 185.9kbits/s dup=1831 drop=0 speed=0.98x
[aac @ 0x5636d32c18c0] Qavg: 435.190

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

So does it “work wrong” or does it not work at all? Please provide the exact ffmpeg command line you are using to get QuickSync-accelerated video encoding, including any relevant output from this ffmpeg call.
